# javascript - how to accomplish getting variable (data) from client side to a database online server?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

so on client side running in the browser I have a javascript code that has a variable (namely a url that is 1500 characters long), and which I need to insert it into a online database that lives on the webserver where I have hosted my website. I have these two technologies on my website, mysql DB and PHP.

Please kindly would someone recommend the best way to do this?
showing examples, specifically, how to send this data over to the remote server and how to process return data it may send back to me??

what i was thinking if there's a way to send over this variable string that is 1500 characters long, over to a PHP file living on my website which this PHP file will be able to insert the data into the DB, and then some time afterwards my same script running on the client browser will check and pull data from the remote DB back to itself...... I've tried to follow along some example searches googling but none of them are making sense to me, sorry I am visual learner , and would greatly appreciate any help you may provide me with this task .....

Comment: There are literally a thousand tutorials for this and this wouldn't make any difference to answer your question here

Comment: Stack Overflow is for helping with specific coding problems, not your project requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The solution already discussed here is the proper one. You need an API (also called a service). 
I don't know who downvoted it but its the right one.
And you need it for several reasons.

1. Performance issues. Your solution "writting to a file" will be slow. And even "writting to a file" will require a service on top.
2. Security reasons. To allow in any other kind of way for a user to write in your server directly (FTP or other methods) is a big security risk and your server might end up being attacked.
3. Scalability and mantainance.

I would recommend reading more at 
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340

And if you are a bigginer an want to start something fast [loopback](https://loopback.io) is an amazing option, but you need NodeJS in your server.

Answer (score -1):

In broad terms what you need to do is set up a API on the PHP side of things. Basically you want a structure where your javascript can send the request, and then, using promises, wait till it gets a response to get the data. That way your PHP server can take however long it needs to put the data in the database and process it properly.

Here's a tutorial on how to make a [restful api in php](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/)